# Spring LdapTemplate is not initialized - Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap

thanks for you help.

I declare my class variable :

```
public class HttpLdapDao {
   private LdapTemplate ldapResetEnveloppe;
```

I initialize this variable in a function :

```
public boolean testADMCredential(Credential credential, Environment env) {
    ...
    LdapContextSource newContext = new LdapContextSource();

    newContext.setBase(baseDn);
    newContext.setUserDn(userDn);
    newContext.setPassword(password);
    newContext.setUrl(url);
    newContext.afterPropertiesSet();

    ldapResetEnveloppe = new LdapTemplate(newContext);
    ...
}
```

And when I want to use my variable ldapResetEnveloppe in an another function :

```
public boolean updateLdapUser(Enveloppe enveloppe, Environment env) {
       System.out.println(ldapResetEnveloppe.list(baseDn));
       ... 
 }
```

I have this error message :

```
org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'ou=people,dc=****,dc=****'
```

And I'm sur I call the first function before.

Could you explain me why ?

Comment: YESS !  I've deleted "newContext.setBase(baseDn);" and everything works. thanks you :)